# How to display percentage result with jquery percentage slider

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Am making use of jquery percentage slider and i need to get the variable and retrieve the percentage value from jquery percentage slider but am having issues for instance i scroll down to 30% i want able to get that value

This is my code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-horizontal" ).slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            value: 0,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
               $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });

        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-horizontal" ).slider( "value" ) );

    });  
</script>
```

Percentage:

```
<div id="slider-horizontal" style="height:8px; width:200px"></div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `amount` on the `slide:` option so all you need to do to get the value is check `amount`.

```
var value = $('#amount').val();
```